# JQuery and XSLT

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt

Good day,
 I have stumbled upon a bug or some strange behaviour and I can't find the solution anywhere.

I use XSLT to display HTML from a XML document. Inside that stylehsheet, I use javascript/jQuery to add some contents. But apparently you can not append anything but texts to any container.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        $("div#topbanner" ).html('<img src="images/load-top.gif" class="load" />');
    });
]]>
```

It's working perfectly under Firefox but with IE7, after the codes execution, only the unrendered HTML appears into my DIV. Like if the `<>` got replaced by `&gt; &lt;` respectively.

To make it work under IE7, I must take out the CDATA tag but doing so, Firefox do not render it.

Is there a way to make the information into the html method execute as html code?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "into the html method".. html method means the jQuery.html method. The equivalent of innerHTML

Answer (score 2):

Embedded Javascript & XSLT = Insanity ;-)

The solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<xsl:comment><![CDATA[
        $(function() {
            $("div#topbanner" ).html('<img src="images/load-top.gif" class="load" />');
        });
    //]]></xsl:comment>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. I must keep my javascript in a external file.

Thank you to anyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this when I forget to use

```
disable-output-escaping="yes"
```

in my `<xslvalue-of../>`

Comment: I heard about that function but where am I going to add it in my javascript?

I want to be able to execute the javascript so I have to include it into CDATA tag but I need my Javascript/JQuery function to execute real HTML and not it's version with entities.

I've googled a bit and it seems to be a known behaviour when using innerHTML into Javascript when its run into a XSLT stylesheet. But none has any solutions.

Do you? :)

Steve

Comment: I guess I don't understand then.  Is it the jquery code (above) not working as expected, or is it the XSLT (not shown)?  I was assuming the XSLT was rendering the &gt; and &lt;.  Maybe more information/sample code is needed to answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try this?

```
<![CDATA[
 $(function() {
  $("<img>").addClass("load").attr("src","images/load-top.gif").appendTo("div#topbanner");
 });
]]>
```

or if that still doesn't work... try this method

```
<![CDATA[
 $(function() {
  myimg = new Image();
  $(myimg).addClass("load").attr("src","images/load-top.gif").appendTo("div#topbanner");
 });
]]>
```